# How to access nested grid view rows from parent RowUpdating method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a child grid view which add to parent grid view in parent RowDataBound. On parent editing, all the child gridview rows are ready to edit. It means that child doesn't have edit itself. How can I get child gridview rows in parent RowUpdating to save edited data?

```
 protected void gvEquipment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {  
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView gvChild = new GridView();
        gvChild.DataSource = dt;
        gvChild.CssClass = "NestedGrid";
        gvChild.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvChild_RowDataBound);

        //Create the show/hide button which will be displayed on each row of the main GridView
        Image imgCollapse = new Image();
        imgCollapse.ID = "btnCollapse";
        imgCollapse.ImageUrl = "~/images/Collapse.gif";
        //Add the javascript function to the show/hide button, passing the row to be toggled as a parameter");
        imgCollapse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: gvrowtoggle(" + (e.Row.RowIndex + e.Row.RowIndex + 2) + ")");

        //Add the expanded details row after each record in the main GridView
        Table tb1 = e.Row.Parent as Table;
        GridViewRow tr = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex + 1, -1, DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        tr.CssClass = "hidden";
        string sr = (e.Row.RowIndex + e.Row.RowIndex + 2).ToString();
        tr.ID = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.ColumnSpan = gvEquipment.Columns.Count + 3;//e.Row.Cells.Count;
        tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        //tc.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        tc.Controls.Add(gvChild);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        tb1.Rows.Add(tr);
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(imgCollapse);
        e.Row.CssClass = "GridAltItem";
        gvChild.DataBind();


     if (IsEditMode && e.Row.RowIndex == EditIndex)
     {
         // edit mode for childGrid
         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
             for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
             {
                 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                 txt.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                 gvChild.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls.Add(txt);
             }
     }
    }
}

 protected void gvEquipment_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
      GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
      //how to get child gridview controls?
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the child gridview:

```
GridViewRow ParentRow = gvEquipment.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;
Table tb = ParentRow .Parent as Table;
GridView gvChild = (GridView)tb.Rows[e.rowIndex +3].Cells[0].Controls[0];
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvChild.Rows)
 {
       //do update                         
 }
```

Comment: Great that you found the way by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

After you added "gvChild" control into the parent GridView then you can use **FindControl** method to get "gvChild" control. See the sample below.

```
protected void gvEquipment_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvEquipment.Rows[e.RowIndex] as GridViewRow;
    GridView gvChild = row.FindControl("gvChild") as GridView;

    //Loop to get data rows
    foreach (GridViewRow item in gvChild.Rows)
    {
        //get data row of gvChild here
    }
}
```

Comment: gvChild  is null because I add(inject) a row to gridview in RowDataBound.It's not in row with e.RowIndex nor e.RowIndex+1. I tried both and couldn't find the child gridview.

Comment: I even tried like what I add in RowDataBound:                                   Table tb = ParentGridRow.Parent as Table;
TableRow gvrow2 = tb.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
GridView gvChild2 = (GridView)gvrow2.FindControl("gvChild");           but still is null.

Answer (score 0):

But the problem now is the child Grid view loose its edited values because it binds again on data binding. The parent grid view has dynamic columns and it needs to bind again on every post back. how to keep the child grid values to perform update?